# VBA - Excel insert row above for each cell containing certain text

Tags: excel, vba, row

How do you go through the specific worksheet and in  a specific column for every row that contains word "firewall" - then insert an empty row above? The Row with "firewall" may be followed by rows that contain other values. The last line in the column is always "Grand Total". I supposed can be used as condition to stop the loop.

I found on Stack Overflow this example which is almost exactly what I need, but it does it only once, and I need through the entire column for all matches. The worksheet should be specified.

```
Sub NewRowInsert()
Dim SearchText As String
Dim GCell As Range

SearchText = "Original"
Set GCell = Worksheets("Sheet2").Cells.Find(SearchText).Offset(1)
GCell.EntireRow.Insert

End Sub
```

**My data example:**

```
firewall abc
policy x
policy y 
firewall xyz  
policy z 
policy xxx 
Grand Total
```

Comment: What is the name of the Sheet, and which is the column with the data?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

### Insert Rows (Find feat. Union)

```vb
Option Explicit

Sub NewRowInsert()
    
    Const sText As String = "FirEWaLL"
    
    Dim wb As Workbook: Set wb = ThisWorkbook ' workbook containing this code
    Dim ws As Worksheet: Set ws = wb.Worksheets("Sheet1")
    Dim LastRow As Long: LastRow = ws.Cells(ws.Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp).Row
    Dim rg As Range: Set rg = ws.Range("A2:A" & LastRow)
    Dim sCell As Range: Set sCell = rg.Find(sText, , xlFormulas, xlPart)
    
    Application.ScreenUpdating = False
    
    Dim trg As Range
    Dim sCount As Long
    
    If Not sCell Is Nothing Then
        Dim FirstAddress As String: FirstAddress = sCell.Address
        Do
            If trg Is Nothing Then
                Set trg = sCell
            Else
                Set trg = Union(trg, sCell.Offset(, sCount Mod 2))
            End If
            sCount = sCount + 1
            Set sCell = rg.FindNext(sCell)
        Loop Until sCell.Address = FirstAddress
        trg.EntireRow.Insert
    End If
    
    Application.ScreenUpdating = True
    
    Select Case sCount
    Case 0
        MsgBox "'" & sText & "' not found.", vbExclamation, "Fail?"
    Case 1
        MsgBox "Found 1 occurrence of '" & sText & "'.", _
            vbInformation, "Success"
    Case Else
        MsgBox "Found " & sCount & " occurrences of '" & sText & "'.", _
            vbInformation, "Success"
    End Select

End Sub
```

Comment: Hello, thank you very much for helping, the script is just perfectly working. The only problem is it doesn't allow me to run it from under PERSONAL.XLSB. Is it possible to change it, so I can use this macro for any file that I open?

Comment: With a little tweak, it will. Instead of `ThisWorkbook` you could use the workbook where you want to apply it e.g. `Worbooks("Whatever.xlsx")`, or `ActiveWorkbook`. Also, adjust the worksheet name or use `ActiveSheet`.

Comment: If you mean the following: You open a file, select a worksheet, and run the code. Then open another file, select a worksheet, and run the code...etc. Then delete or out-comment the `Dim wb...` line, and change the next line to: `Dim ws As Worksheet: Set ws = ActiveSheet`.

Comment: Yes, I've changed it to ActiveWorkbook and all is good now! One more time thanks you!